Can I use Sqlitedb as database for my mobile application that would run in platforms like Android and IOS?
I am new to mobile application development.
I am in the process of building a mobile application using Flutter 3.4.1 and SQLLiteDB using Android Studio IDE.
I now need to run the mobile application in IOS devices too.
Questions:

Can I use Sqlitedb as database for my mobile application that would run in platforms like Android and IOS?
Which database can be used for both Android and IOS mobile apps?


According to the official docs:

SQLite is built into all mobile phones and most computers and comes
bundled inside countless other applications that people use every day

And, yes. It works on both: Android and iOS. Both platforms are shipped with sqlite engine.
All you need is to check the Flutter doc on using Sqlite and you're good to go: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/sqlite
